# How to properly configure HDFS high availability using Zookeeper?

Tags: hdfs, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

I'm a student of big data. I'm coming to you today for a question about the high availability of HDFS using Zookeeper. I am aware that there has already been bcp of topic dealing with this subject, I have read a lot of them already. It's already been 15 days that I've been browsing the forums without finding what I'm looking for (maybe I'm not looking in the right place too ;-) )

I have followed the procedure three times here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html.

I may have done everything right, but when I kill one of my namenodes, none of them take over.

My architecture is as follows:
- 5 VM
- VM 1,3 and 5 are namenodes
- VMs 1 to 5 are datanodes.

I launched my journalnodes, I started my DFSZKFailoverController, I formatted my first namenode, I copied with -bootstrapStandby the configuration of my first namenode to the 2 others and I started my cluster.

Despite all this and no obvious problems in the ZKFC and namenode logs, I can't get a namenode to take over a dying namenode.

Does anyone have any idea how to help me?

Many thanks for your help :)

**zoo.cfg**

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=5
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=2
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
dataDir=/home/zookeeper/zoo
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the 
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1

## Metrics Providers
#
# https://prometheus.io Metrics Exporter
#metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider
#metricsProvider.httpPort=7000
#metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true

admin.serverPort=7979

server.1=10.10.10.15:2888:3888
server.2=10.10.10.16:2888:3888
server.3=10.10.10.17:2888:3888
server.4=10.10.10.18:2888:3888
server.5=10.10.10.19:2888:3888
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

    <!-- default configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://my-cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
        <value>131072</value>
    </property>

    <!-- zookeeper configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>10.10.10.15:2181,10.10.10.16:2181,10.10.10.17:2181,10.10.10.18:2181,10.10.10.19:2181</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- cluster configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>my-cluster</value>
    </property>

    <!-- namenode configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdfs/data/nameNode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- datanode configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdfs/data/dataNode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- secondary namenode configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdfs/data/secondaryNameNode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- replication factor -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>

    <!-- webhdfs connector -->
    <property> 
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name> 
        <value>true</value> 
    </property> 

    <!-- high-availability configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.my-cluster</name>
        <value>nn1,nn2,nn3</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.my-cluster.nn1</name>
        <value>10.10.10.15:9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.my-cluster.nn2</name>
        <value>10.10.10.19:9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.my-cluster.nn3</name>
        <value>10.10.10.17:9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.my-cluster.nn1</name>
        <value>10.10.10.15:9870</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.my-cluster.nn2</name>
        <value>10.10.10.19:9870</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.my-cluster.nn3</name>
        <value>10.10.10.17:9870</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
        <value>qjournal://10.10.10.15:8485;10.10.10.19:8485;10.10.10.17:8485/my-cluster</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hdfs/data/journalNode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- failover configuration -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.my-cluster</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
        <value>sshfence</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
        <value>/home/hdfsuser/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

**dfs.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Hadoop DFS namenode and datanode
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
User=hdfsuser
Group=hdfsgroup
Type=simple
ExecStart=/apps/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
ExecStop=/apps/hadoop/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**hadoop-hdfsuser-zkfc-node15-hdfs-spark-master.log**
*(before i crash a namenode)*

```
2020-04-09 13:32:22,216 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DFSZKFailoverController
STARTUP_MSG:   host = node15-hdfs-spark-master/10.10.10.15
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 3.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /apps/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-xdr-1.0.1.jar:/apps/hadoop/share/hado$STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b3cbbb467e22ea829b3808f4b7b01d07e0bf3842; compiled by 'rohithsharmaks' on 2019-09-10T15:56Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_242
************************************************************/
2020-04-09 13:32:22,229 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2020-04-09 13:32:22,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: Failover controller configured for NameNode NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000
2020-04-09 13:32:22,751 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=node15
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_242
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/apps/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:/apps/hadoo$2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/apps/hadoop/lib/native
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2020-04-09 13:32:22,756 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hdfsuser
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hdfsuser
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hdfsuser
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=node15:2181,node16:2181,node17:2181,node18:2181,node19:2181 sessionTimeout=10000 wat$2020-04-09 13:32:22,777 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node19/10.10.10.19:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-04-09 13:32:22,784 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to node19/10.10.10.19:2181, initiating session
2020-04-09 13:32:22,817 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server node19/10.10.10.19:2181, sessionid = 0x50000a3038f0000, negotiated timeout = 10000
2020-04-09 13:32:22,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Session connected.
2020-04-09 13:32:22,864 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 300, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.$2020-04-09 13:32:22,888 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8019
2020-04-09 13:32:22,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2020-04-09 13:32:22,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8019: starting
2020-04-09 13:32:23,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor: Entering state SERVICE_HEALTHY
2020-04-09 13:32:23,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Local service NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 entered state: SERVICE_HEALTHY
2020-04-09 13:32:23,074 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Checking for any old active which needs to be fenced...
2020-04-09 13:32:23,085 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Old node exists: 0a0a6d792d636c757374657212036e6e321a06686466732d3420a84628d33e
2020-04-09 13:32:23,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Should fence: NameNode at hdfs-4/10.10.10.19:9000
2020-04-09 13:32:23,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Successfully transitioned NameNode at hdfs-4/10.10.10.19:9000 to standby state without fencing
2020-04-09 13:32:23,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Writing znode /hadoop-ha/my-cluster/ActiveBreadCrumb to indicate that the local node is the most recent active...
2020-04-09 13:32:23,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Trying to make NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 active...
2020-04-09 13:32:23,759 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Successfully transitioned NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 to active state
```

**hadoop-hdfsuser-zkfc-node15-hdfs-spark-master.log**
*(after i crash a namenode)*

```
2020-04-09 13:32:22,216 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DFSZKFailoverController
STARTUP_MSG:   host = node15-hdfs-spark-master/10.10.10.15
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 3.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /apps/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-xdr-1.0.1.jar:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-$STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b3cbbb467e22ea829b3808f4b7b01d07e0bf3842; compiled by 'rohithsharmaks' on 2019-09-10T15:56Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_242
************************************************************/
2020-04-09 13:32:22,229 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2020-04-09 13:32:22,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: Failover controller configured for NameNode NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000
2020-04-09 13:32:22,751 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=node15
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_242
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre
2020-04-09 13:32:22,752 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/apps/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/kerby-util-1.0.1.jar:/apps/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/$2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/apps/hadoop/lib/native
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2020-04-09 13:32:22,753 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2020-04-09 13:32:22,756 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hdfsuser
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hdfsuser
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hdfsuser
2020-04-09 13:32:22,757 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=node15:2181,node16:2181,node17:2181,node18:2181,node19:2181 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.ha.$2020-04-09 13:32:22,777 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node19/10.10.10.19:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-04-09 13:32:22,784 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to node19/10.10.10.19:2181, initiating session
2020-04-09 13:32:22,817 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server node19/10.10.10.19:2181, sessionid = 0x50000a3038f0000, negotiated timeout = 10000
2020-04-09 13:32:22,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Session connected.
2020-04-09 13:32:22,864 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 300, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, i$2020-04-09 13:32:22,888 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8019
2020-04-09 13:32:22,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2020-04-09 13:32:22,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8019: starting
2020-04-09 13:32:23,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor: Entering state SERVICE_HEALTHY
2020-04-09 13:32:23,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Local service NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 entered state: SERVICE_HEALTHY
2020-04-09 13:32:23,074 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Checking for any old active which needs to be fenced...
2020-04-09 13:32:23,085 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Old node exists: 0a0a6d792d636c757374657212036e6e321a06686466732d3420a84628d33e
2020-04-09 13:32:23,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Should fence: NameNode at hdfs-4/10.10.10.19:9000
2020-04-09 13:32:23,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Successfully transitioned NameNode at hdfs-4/10.10.10.19:9000 to standby state without fencing
2020-04-09 13:32:23,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Writing znode /hadoop-ha/my-cluster/ActiveBreadCrumb to indicate that the local node is the most recent active...
2020-04-09 13:32:23,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Trying to make NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 active...
2020-04-09 13:32:23,759 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Successfully transitioned NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 to active state
2020-04-09 13:38:59,910 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor: Transport-level exception trying to monitor health of NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000
java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is: "node15-hdfs-spark-master/10.10.10.15"; destination host is: "hdfs-0":9000; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/ha$
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:833)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getServiceStatus(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.protocolPB.HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.getServiceStatus(HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor.doHealthChecks(HealthMonitor.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor.access$600(HealthMonitor.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor$MonitorDaemon.run(HealthMonitor.java:296)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1079)
2020-04-09 13:38:59,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor: Entering state SERVICE_NOT_RESPONDING
2020-04-09 13:38:59,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Local service NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 entered state: SERVICE_NOT_RESPONDING
2020-04-09 13:38:59,938 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController: Can't get local NN thread dump due to Connexion refusée (Connection refused)
2020-04-09 13:38:59,938 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Quitting master election for NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000 and marking that fencing is necessary
2020-04-09 13:38:59,938 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Yielding from election
2020-04-09 13:38:59,947 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x50000a3038f0000 closed
2020-04-09 13:38:59,947 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Ignoring stale result from old client with sessionId 0x50000a3038f0000
2020-04-09 13:38:59,947 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x50000a3038f0000
2020-04-09 13:39:01,951 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=1, sleepTime=10$2020-04-09 13:39:01,953 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor: Transport-level exception trying to monitor health of NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000
java.net.ConnectException: Call From node15-hdfs-spark-master/10.10.10.15 to hdfs-0:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/ha$
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:833)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getServiceStatus(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.protocolPB.HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.getServiceStatus(HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor.doHealthChecks(HealthMonitor.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor.access$600(HealthMonitor.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor$MonitorDaemon.run(HealthMonitor.java:296)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:804)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
        ... 8 more
2020-04-09 13:39:03,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=1, sleepTime=10$2020-04-09 13:39:03,958 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor: Transport-level exception trying to monitor health of NameNode at hdfs-0/10.10.10.15:9000
java.net.ConnectException: Call From node15-hdfs-spark-master/10.10.10.15 to hdfs-0:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/ha$
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:833)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getServiceStatus(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.protocolPB.HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.getServiceStatus(HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor.doHealthChecks(HealthMonitor.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor.access$600(HealthMonitor.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.HealthMonitor$MonitorDaemon.run(HealthMonitor.java:296)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:804)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
        ... 8 more
...
...
...
```

Comment: Please post your configuration files, for both HDFS and Zookeeper

Comment: thanks @franklinsijo
i just add three conf file : zoo.cfg, core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Comment: A few questions, 1) did you format zkfc? 2) Is passwordless ssh enabled? 3) Were you able to access the Namenode web UI, did one say as active and other as standby?

Comment: 1. yes, i use "hdfs zkfc -formatZK" to format space between HDFS and ZooKeeper

2. yes, i use ssh-keygen to generate RSA key on each node and send them to each node with ssh-copy-id

3. yes, at the instant i have 3 namenodes and the command "hdfs haadmin -getAllServiceState" says:

(node15:9000  --->  active), 
(node19:9000  --->  standby),
(node17:9000  --->  standby)

Comment: What happens when you transition the active node to standy? All 3 remain in standby?

Comment: just tested : using "hdfs haadmin -transitionToStandby --forcemanual nn1" make nn2 active

Comment: Did `transitionToStandby` command made another namenode to active state?

Comment: yes, each time i use this command another node become active

Comment: but when i kill active namenode, none of the other become active

Comment: and if i restart manually the node i've killed, a new active node is elected !

Comment: Are there any entries in the Zookeeper log?

Comment: i've just wildly killed a namenode and see all zookeeper log at this precise time ... for each VM, nothing (0 byte) in zookeeper_audit.log and nothing wrong in zookeeper-zookeeper-server-nodeXX.out

Comment: `zkfc` is running in all namenodes right?

Comment: how can i know if zkfc run correctly on one node ?

Comment: `jps` should list if it is running and it must be running in all nodes.

Comment: on node15, node17 and node19, for hdfs, i've NameNode, DataNode, JournalNode and DFSZKFailoverController. on node16 and node18, i only have DataNode running

Comment: I just added my systemd service that starts/stops dfs services. Since the namenode doesn't restart automatically when it crashes, maybe my error comes from the way I launch the namenodes?

Comment: since a new namenode is automatically elected as active namenode when I manually restart a crashed namenode, I searched yesterday and this morning why zookeeper doesn't automatically restart my crashed namenode! but I couldn't find anything that would explain this

Comment: @franklinsijo do you have any idea what might be blocking it? I feel like we're close to the truth, but the last step seems ungraspable to me

Comment: We need ZKFC logs to understand what is happening, but we are unable to find anything in there! My suspicion is with the sshfence.

Comment: @franklinsijo well, the problem is definitely with the sshfence. I don't know why yet, but it's definitely there. 

I replaced "sshfence" in my "dfs.ha.fencing.methods" property with "shell(/bin/true)" and disabled the other properties related to sshfence. when I kill one of my nodes, the next one automatically takes over within 5 seconds

Comment: after research, i managed to get my high availability HDFS working using sshfence. According to the link provided below, I configured my sshfence as follows:


```<property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
        <value>
            sshfence
            shell(bin/true)
        </value>
    </property>```

Comment: Link to the article : [link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Y-wtAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT78&lpg=PT78&dq=why+sshfence+fail&source=bl&ots=VH_UICGJ83&sig=ACfU3U1NQRYQybHkFmV4C6-ZkOr-x_sBVA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXmdnnoOfoAhUPDGMBHTndBY4Q6AEwBHoECAsQPA#v=onepage&q=why%20sshfence%20fail&f=false)

Comment: By providing both sshfence and shell, you are actually creating a fallback. In case sshfence fails, it is going to use shell. The problem of why sshfence was not working is not solved!

Comment: OK :( ... but I've exhausted the list of reasons why the sshfence might not work. Configuring `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` OK, SSH keys on each host OK, SSH communication between hosts OK, DFSZKFailoverController, lognodes, namenodes and datanodes working fine, installing the `nc` command to make the sshfence work OK ... I don't see it anymore...

Comment: I finally found the source of the problem. It lacked a useful method (fuser) for sshfence. It certainly didn't set up at the same time as hadoop.
i manually installed the psmisc package, removed shell(/bin/true) from my hdfs-site.xml file, restarted my hadoop cluster and killed the active namenode (node17). the namenode of VM node19 immediately took the role of active namenode
thanks for your help

Comment: Finally! Great catch, how did you figure it out? Also update a detailed answer, it will help many.

Comment: To find this, I stopped my cluster, deleted the logs on all nodes, restarted the cluster and ran a `watch -n 2 tail -20 /apps/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hdfsuser-zkfc-nodeXX.log` on each datanode.

and, when I killed my active node, I saw "Fusing: command not found" so I deduced that it was not installed... `yum install -y psmisc.x86_64` and you know the rest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with my configuration finally came from two commands that hadn't been installed when I installed the hadoop cluster:

- first the nc command: fixed by installing the nmap package from yum
- then the command fuser: fixed by installing the psmisc package from yum

```
yum install -y nmap.x86_64
yum install -y psmisc.x86_64
```

Hopefully it will help other of you soon.